# Split screen with Android Go pie

Tags: 9.0-pie, multi-window, android-go

If I understand it correctly, the only thing that makes an Android ROM a "Go" version is the "ro.config.low_ram=true" entry, which brings several optimizations for low end devices and improves the performance by disabling some of the android features. One of them is the ability to display two apps simultaneously on the screen, using the split screen function.

So my question is - can only the split screen (or multi-window) function be enabled on an Android pie Go ROM, without disabling all other "Go" optimizations?

I'm using Resurrection Remix pie [ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/development/9-0-resurrection-remix-v7-0-t3899373) on a Motorola Moto E 2015 phone.

Comment: According to me, it can't be done, because running two apps side-by-side requires a large amount of memory (RAM).

Comment: Well, I used to run two apps in split screen with RR nougat just fine on the same phone, occasionally. Maybe the pie version of android needs more ram, and the experience could be choppy, but I guess it could be done with pie also, by disabling the low ram entry. But then all other low ram optimizations would be lost, which probably help the phone run smoother all the time. On the other hand, split screen can be toggled so it should only affect the performance, when it is enabled.